# Node js read a value from json array

Tags: json, node.js

```
async.series([
function(callback){
            geen.api('OpenOrders', function(error, data) {
            callback(null, data.result['open']);
            if(error) {
            console.log(error);
             }


            });
            }   
],
function(err, results){
    console.log(results[0]['OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP'].status) // undefined


});
});
```

returns this json:

```
    [{ 'OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP':
             {  refid: null,
                userred: null,
                status: 'open',
                opentm: 1397461378.8155
             }
    }]
```

How do I acces this? For example:  results['OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP'].status
I get an undefined.

Comment: Please console.log(results) and tell me what you have there

Comment: you should also fix your question to have results[0]['OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP'].status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array and OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP is at the first position so:
`results[0]['OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP'].status`

if you would like to access it the way you show you would have to have the array formed like this:

```
var results = [];  
results['OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP'] = {  
    refid: null,  
    userred: null,  
    status: 'open',  
    pentm: 1397461378.8155  
}
```

Now results['OJVBCE-KZ7SX-SNNAAP'].status will work

Comment: Maybe I did not show enough code in my question. I added some more.